# OAuth 2.0, app server - WebSphere Liberty - unclear redirect to microsoft after 10 minutes

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, oauth, websphere-liberty

I have simple REST service with integrated Swagger UI, application server - WepSphere Liberty,
I have successfully implemented Authorization Code flow for OAuth 2.0 authorization using openidConnectClient feature. Works fine, user is logging on microsoft site and successfully redirected to my webapp.
Problem is that after **10 minutes** when I try to execute simple request to server via Swagger UI I get an error

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">var loc=window.location.href;document.cookie="WASReqURLOidcn377114111="+loc+"; path=/;"</script><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">window.location.replace("https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=.......</script>
<title>Redirect To OP</title> 
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

server.xml:

```
    <authFilter id="app-filter">
        <requestHeader id="excludeBearer" name="Authorization" value="Bearer" matchType="notContain"/>
        <requestHeader id="excludeBasic" name="Authorization" value="Basic" matchType="notContain"/>
    </authFilter>
    <openidConnectClient id="app-oidc"
                         authFilterRef="app-filter"
                         useSystemPropertiesForHttpClientConnections="true"
                         jwkEndpointUrl="https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/discovery/v2.0/keys"
                         issuerIdentifier="https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/v2.0"
                         audiences="<clientId of our application>"
                         userIdentityToCreateSubject="<our custom claim>"
                         mapIdentityToRegistryUser="false"
                         inboundPropagation="none"
                         signatureAlgorithm="RS256"
                         tokenReuse="true"
                         clientId="..."
                         clientSecret="..."
                         authorizationEndpointUrl="https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"
                         tokenEndpointUrl="https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token"
                         responseType="code"
                         groupIdentifier="roles"
                         sslRef="defaultSSLConfig">
    </openidConnectClient>
```

Looks like something happens and it tries to authorize again
It's strange for me, default oauth token lifetime is 1h30m, I even don't know what is exactly going on

Could somebody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that is due to Liberty cache expiration, and the cached subject has been removed. There are multiple ways to address this problem, and following is what I prefer.

1: add `<authnCache timeout="1800s" />`  this change cache timeout from default 10 minutes to 30 minutes.

(Optional) 2: add disableLtpaCookie="true" to openidConnectClient configuration element, which will use id_token lifetime as security session time.

3: add isClientSideRedirectSupported="false" to openidConnectClient configuration element, which avid the javascript, and directly redirect browser to IdP for login.

Comment: Thanks! it helped!
More info about liberty cache: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_sec_cache.html

server.xml setting:
`<authCache timeout="1h"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, but I have a few questions/comments.

- What specific error?
- After the Microsoft authorization, you should
  get a authorization token, but do you request the access token?
- Does the request work before those 10 minutes
- Also, double check your URL requests to see if any mistakes in the query.

Comment: Actually, there is no any error in the meaning of "something does not work". We observe attempt to re-login after 10 minutes, just like if session timeout is 10 minutes. The question is: where do these 10 minutes come from and how can we manage this timeout? First 10 minutes all works fine
All other config is fine: we are able to login (i.e. redirect URLs are set up correctly and we retrieve and use access_token. openidConnectClient feature does this magic).

Answer (score 0):

@Chunlong

Could you, please, give some more info about cache timeout? Is this about `authCache`? ([IBM docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_sec_cache.html))

P.S. Just a small note regarding isClientRedirectSupported="false": if use this feature, servlet provided by openidConnectClientFeature will not send back 302 when go to application. Instead of it -- servlet will respond with status 200 and html with self-submitting form. Technically -- it is not redirect, but result will be the same: browser will display IdP's login page.

(Sadly, have no enough reputation to comment)

Comment: Yes, the link you posted is correct. For example, to set cache time out  to 30 minutes, add  authnCache timeout="1800s"

Comment: @Chunlong, thanks a lot! Did not know about such layer of WLP...